# Intent Filter is not working as expcted

Tags: android, android-intent

Hi i created an android project in which i make a main activity

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String ss="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=anonymous&redirect_uri=https://cloudspokeproject.appspot.com/oauth2callback&response_type=code&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings  https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/groups/";

            Uri url=Uri.parse(ss);
            Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,url);
            startActivity(in);


    }
```

and then created a Response Activity
with code

```
public class Response extends Activity {

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        TextView text=new TextView(this);
    Uri uri=this.getIntent().getData();
    String code=uri.getQueryParameter("code");
    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token");

         String param="code="+code+"&client_id=anonymous&client_secret=anonymous&redirect_uri=https://cloudspokeproject.appspot.com/oauth2callback&grant_type=authorization_code";

         HttpURLConnection connection = 
    (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection(); 
         connection.setDoOutput(true); 
         connection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
         connection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
         connection.getOutputStream().write( param.getBytes() ); 
      InputStream str= connection.getInputStream();
      BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(str));
    String l="";
    String l1="";
    while((l=reader.readLine())!=null){
        l1+=l;
    }
        text.setText(l1);
        setContentView(text);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }}
```

and here is my menifest file code

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
 <activity
     android:name=".Response"
     android:label="Hello World"
     android:exported="false">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/> 
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/> 
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
          <data android:host="cloudspokeproject.appspot.com/oauth2callback" android:scheme="https"/> 
          </intent-filter>
 </activity>


</application>
```

i am trying to implement google Authentication for an app and Main Activity is opening a google login and after signing in it is redirected to  clouspokeproject.appspot.com/oauth2callback  but as i put an intent filter in  Response activity in menifest .when url cloudspokeproject.apspot.com/oauth2callback is called in browser then  android should redirect it to activity Response.i successfully implemented oauth for twitter and couple of other apis but this time its not redirecting to Response activity
can any one please tell where i am wrong.i know mistake is very minor please point me so that i can rectify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi for returning back to my my activity intent filter should be like

```
<intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/> 
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/> 
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
          <data android:host="cloudspokeproject.appspot.com" android:scheme="https"/> 
          </intent-filter>
```

i have to remove /oauth2callback in host attribute because its a very rare url and used for only once in project so its working fine for me now.

Answer (score 0):

you are firing an intent to open a browser not to call your Response activity

Comment: yes i am firing an intent to open a browser in Intent in=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,url);
            startActivity(in);
but i am also applying intent filter for getting back to my activity .